# Bash equivalent of Ruby and JavaScript OR when initializing variables

Tags: javascript, ruby, bash, initialization, logical-operators

Sometimes I see in JavaScript:

```
a||=1
```

Which means - as far as I know - that if "a" is not defined, or null then it was initialized with value 1, otherwise nothing happens. I do the same in Ruby scripts, for example when a command line argument wasn't passed:

```
gamma=ARGV[0]||"1.0"
```

Then variable gamma gets its value from ARGV[0] assuming it is not nil, a value was passed, otherwise it will be "1.0".

It is a great shorthand for:

```
if ARGV[0]==nil then
  gamma="1.0"
else 
  gamma=ARGV[0]
end
```

and even:

```
gamma=ARGV[0]==nil ? "1.0" : ARGV[0]
```

I would like to use a similar cinstruction in a ruby script, but it doesn't work as expected, because a nil or null value doesn't exist, so expression:

```
$0||"1.0"
```

always gives the value of $0, even if it is an empty string "".
Is it possible to use something similar shorthand syntax in bash scripts too?

Comment: Note: in JavaScript you do `foo = foo || bar`, there's no `||=` operator (yet).

Comment: And in Ruby everything except nil and false is considered true, even empty strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash` you can use the *Assign Default Values* parameter [expansion operator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

```
: ${a:=1.0}
```

> `${parameter:=word}`
>   If `parameter` is unset or null, the expansion of `word` is assigned to `parameter`.

The `:` command is a no-op, it's used just so we can perform the parameter expansion in its argument list.